# Can't Delete Root Trash

Tags: usb-drive, disk-usage, gnome-shell-extension

In Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I run Disk Usage Analyzer (DUA) as root (`sudo baobab`). It shows me two different USB drives: one booted, the other bootable, both mounted. Both have the same problem.

The problem is that DUA says /root/.local/share/Trash/files contains 7.2GB in 4052 items; but although they are in Trash, they cannot be deleted.

In `sudo nautilus`, with /root/.local/share/Trash/files selected, I hit Shift-Del. This produces "Error while deleting ... Error removing [filename]: Operation not permitted." I click Skip All. Nautilus then reports that the folder is empty. But a refresh on DUA shows that nothing has changed.

In a Terminal session opened from that root Nautilus session, at ~/.local/share/Trash, `ls` indicates that the folder is still named "files." This disagrees with `sudo nautilus`, which says it has been renamed to "expunged."

In that Terminal session, typing `rm -rf files` produces many instances of "rm: cannot remove [filename]: Operation not permitted." Of course, prepending "sudo" makes no difference.

As I say, the results are the same, regardless of whether I am operating on the booted or nonbooted bootable USB drive.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. In light of the suggestions so far, is there perhaps a non-Linux operating system that can delete that folder? So far, I have not found one that will delete a folder from an ext4 partition.

Comment: Try shift-deleting /root/.local/share/Trash? It should re-generate itself the next time root deletes something.

Comment: Sadly, as already indicated, Shift-Del is sleeping on the job: "Error while deleting ... Operation not permitted."

Comment: Don't *describe* input and output. *Show us* the actual, complete input and output. Simply copy it out of your terminal into your question. For example, it's unclear if you are running these actions as root or as sudo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete them from terminal with sudo.

```
sudo rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/files
```

If that somehow does not work, you can try logging in as root, and deleting the files from the root account, with the following commands.

```
su
rm -rf /root/.local/share/Trash/files
```

Comment: The first of those two looks like one of those listed above, that didn't work previously. Still doesn't work. For the second one, I had to use sudo -i to log in (otherwise "Authentication failure"). But still doesn't work: same "Cannot remove ... Operation not permitted" error. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: It might seem similar, but your Question does not *show us* that you tried this (nor the system response, which would be very helpful), so this answer seems valid for most cases.